# How can I bias this Differential amp. circuit at the best operating point?

Tags: amplifier, differential, differential-amplifier

I'm looking to find a way to bias this circuit:

[image: How to find best operating point]

I've written down a couple of equations for DC load line(and also DC half circuit):

[image]

[image]

and these two as AC Load line:
[image]

[image]

Rc is given by 1K and you can see even by giving DC bias voltage to base pins of transistors, it comes out to have Ic=0 !!!!!
NOW the question is : what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You get yourself lost in formulas without looking at the circuit and thinking about **how it works**. You want to find the biasing point yet you write down small signal parameters like vce and ic, **why**? That is confusing! It is much easier to strictly separate DC biasing and AC behavior. You need to make some assumptions on the behavior of the circuit which will make it easier to analyze, for example the Rc resistors don't influence the DC biasing much as long as the NPNs are in active mode (not saturation).

Comment: Where would that collector current go?  Not to the base, unless the junction breaks down.  Maybe the emitter?  But then where?

Comment: You are asking for the "best" operating point. What is your definition for the term "best" in this case? (High gain ? Small power consumption? Small THD?...)